# Complex forms in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, forms, react-forms

I am working on refactoring a jquery project with multiple complex forms using React. Some of them have 50+ fields, and many are conditionally shown and required based on some previous user selection. There is offcorse a file that deals with displaying and creating these form fields but this is a whole another discussion :D

The original forms are written in PHP and all the fields are customized to have properties used in the project for various purposes. Also some of the fields are being populated by calling the API endpoint.

Ex:

```
$form['formStructure']['creativeBrief']['groupFields']['search_tag'] = [
                                       'description'   => "Search Tag",
                                       'displayOrder'  => "201",
                                       'helpText'      => "",
                                       'structureType' => "text",
                                       'locked'        => "false",
                                       'fieldName'     => "search_tag",
                                       'id'            => "search_tag",
                                       'options'       => [
                                                         'defaultvalue' => "%oi_search_tag%",
                                                         'displaylabel' => "Search Tag",
                                                         'validationRegex' => "/^.{0,128}$/",
                                                         'validationMessage' => "You've exceeded the 128 character limit"
                                                        ],
                                       'required'      => "false"
                                      ];
```

In the new React project, I would like to change this and use something else.
I started looking at [JSON Forms][1]

[1]: https://jsonforms.io/ but so far I think it lacks some of the functionality that I require in these forms.

If anyone could help me and give some suggestions on what is a good library to use in react for rendering and creating these kinds of forms I would be grateful.

Comment: Sorry, asking for library recommendations is OT here

Comment: Thank you, did not know that. Do you maybe know where can I post this question and get the answer to it? Is it ok if I change the question?

Comment: Changing the question is fine, but to be fit for here you need to 1. pick a library 2. try to implement it 3. get stuck 4. read the docs, debug your code, do lots of research 5. still be stuck 6. post code and describe exactly how it fails

Comment: hm.. ok thanks. all of the above is done accept posting code. But I get it

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at React Hook Form and Formik libraries for react forms.
I am personally suggesting use React Hook Form. It's better in performance.

For your reference:
https://react-hook-form.com/

Comment: @Zile - if it helps you, please upvote and accept the answer. It will be helpful for me.